Bluetooth multipoint: Can't play anything on my phone while the MacBook is connected to the headphones
Like most people, I have (non-Apple) Bluetooth multipoint headphones that can simultaneously connect to two devices, and it will automatically play audio from either one of those devices (but never from both simultaneously).
Case 1: connected to a PC (works fine)
If I connect it to my PC (any modern Linux distro; same behavior on Windows) and my Android phone, everything works as expected:

I play something on the PC, and the headphones start playing it. Any audio from the phone is discarded. (Unless it starts ringing.)
I stop playing audio on the PC. The audio goes silent. A few seconds later, the headphones can start playing audio from the phone.

Case 2: connected to a Mac (causes trouble)
If I connect it to a MacBook and my phone, suddenly I'm unable to hear anything from my phone anymore.

I play something on the Mac, and the headphones start playing it. Any audio from the phone is discarded. (Unless it starts ringing.) So far, normal behavior.
I stop playing audio on the Mac. Or I end a video-call. The Mac is now silent. However, any audio from the phone is still being discarded. This is not what the user expects.
I turn off my headphones. Then turn the headphones back on. If I start playing audio from the phone immediately, the headphones do play the audio. However, if I pause the phone for a few seconds, or if I take too long to start playing, the headphones will again be captured by the Mac and will be busy playing silence.

The question(s)
Why does it happen?
Why can't I use my headphones with my phone even though the MacBook is playing no audio?
How can I solve this? Is there any workaround?
Why it matters
It is common to leave the MacBook at our desk while we take a break to go to the toilet or the kitchen. During this period, the MacBook is still hogging the headphones, even though there is nothing but silence.
Non-solutions
Asking the user to always close and restart the video call software (be it Teams, Zooms, or anything else) after each call is too much work and counter-productive. People have many meetings per day, and many chats as well.
Asking the user to close and reopen the browser isn't worth the trouble. Dozens of tabs have to be reloaded. It's also counter-productive.
Asking the user to close Spotify… Well, I wasn't even using Spotify anyway.
Asking the user to close the app sending audio isn't helpful either. The user doesn't know. There is no indication whatsoever. Furthermore, there is no audible audio, it's silent, and no application is playing audio anymore.
A workaround is to go to the Mac interface and manually disconnect the headphones. This isn't a good solution when we are already in the kitchen, far from the MacBook.
Sleeping is a different issue
It is pretty well known that MacBooks keep their Bluetooth enabled even during sleep, and they will keep connected the headphones even though the system is asleep. (I think it's stupid, but Apple will say it's different.) The Bluesnooze app is a well-known workaround for this case. Or you could use sleepwatcher to run a script to enable/disable bluetooth.
This question, however, is not about sleeping. It's about the MacBook still awake, but not playing any audio.
Related questions

Bluetooth multipoint playback on M2 MacBook Pro: can't play on other devices (solved by noTunes)
Prevent macOS Big Sur fom staying connected to bluetooth audio device when put to sleep/closing the lid (sleep issue)
Stop Macbook from stealing Bluetooth audio focus on Bose headphones (sounds related, possibly a duplicate, but no good solution; also didn't show up when I searched, possibly due to the lack of keywords)

